# assign function result to one or more variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, assign

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []); 

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){

 $scope.budget0=60;

 $scope.plusvalenzaResult = 0;

 $scope.calcoloBudget = function(davendere, offerta, budg){
     davendere = parseInt(davendere);
     offerta = parseInt(offerta);
     $scope.newBudget = budg - (offerta - davendere);
     return $scope.newBudget;
 };
    $scope.plusvalenza = function(venduto, acquistato) {
     
         $scope.plusvalenzaResult = venduto - acquistato;
         return $scope.plusvalenzaResult;

         };
         
    $scope.confronto = function(el1,el2){
     
  el1=parseInt(el1);
  el2=parseInt(el2);
  
  if(el1>el2){
   
   return true;
   
  }
  else{
   
   return false;
   
  }
 };
 
 $http.get("rosa.php").success(function(data){
  
  $scope.rose=data;
  
 });
 
    $http.get("giocatoriLiberi.php").success(function(data){
     
  $scope.giocLiberi=data;
  
 }); 
 
 $scope.range = function(start, end) {
  
    var result = [];
    start = parseInt(start); 
    end = parseInt(end);
    
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
     
        result.push(i);
        
    }
    return result;
    
    };
 


});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<!-- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% offerta1-->
<div class="row"> 
   
    <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Vendere:</label> 
              <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>
              <!--<p ng-model="selectedItem1">Selezionato: {{selectedItem1.nome}}</p>-->
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
              <label>Acquistare:</label>
              <select ng-model="giocAcq1" ng-options="(lib.nome+' '+lib.costo) for lib in giocLiberi | filter:{ruolo:selectedItem1.ruolo}"></select>
              <!--<p ng-model="giocAcq1">Da acquistare: {{giocAcq1.nome}}</p>-->
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-1">

              <label>Offerta:</label>
              <select ng-model="off0" style="width: 60px" ng-options="page for page in range(giocAcq1.costo, budget0--selectedItem1.costo)" ></select>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label></label>
        <div ng-model="budget0">Il tuo budget per questa offerta e': <b>{{budget0--selectedItem1.costo}}</b> fantamilioni</div> 
     <!--<p ng-model="plus1" ng-show="selectedItem1.costo > giocAcq1.costo">Questa offerta ti garantisce una plusvalenza di {{plusvalenza(selectedItem1.costo,giocAcq1.costo)}} fantamilioni per la prossima busta</p>-->
     <p ng-model="plus1" ng-show="confronto(selectedItem1.costo, giocAcq1.costo)">Questa offerta ti garantisce una plusvalenza di {{plusvalenza(selectedItem1.costo,off0)}} fantamilioni per la prossima busta nella quale avrai a disposizione </p>
    </div>

<!--<div class="col-md-1">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="selectRosa()">Formalizza l'offerta</button>
 
</div>-->
</div>

<br />
<!-- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% offerta2-->
<div class="row"> 
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
             <label>Vendere:</label>
             <select ng-model="selectedItem2"  ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>
             <p ng-model="selectedItem2">Selezionato: {{selectedItem2.costo}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
             <label>Acquistare:</label>
             <select ng-model="giocAcq2" ng-options="(lib.nome+' '+lib.costo) for lib in giocLiberi | filter:{ruolo:selectedItem2.ruolo}"></select>
             <p ng-model="giocAcq2">Da acquistare: {{giocAcq2.costo}}</p>  
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-1">
             <label>Offerta:</label>
             <select ng-model="off1" style="width: 60px"  ng-options="page for page in range(giocAcq2.costo, budget0-off0--selectedItem2.costo)"></select>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <label></label>
        
        *<div ng-model="budget1" ng-if="selectedItem1.costo < off0">Il tuo budget per questa busta dopo la seconda offerta è: <b>{{budget1=calcoloBudget(selectedItem1.costo, off0, budget0)}}</b> fantamilioni.</div>
        <div ng-model="budget1" ng-if="selectedItem1.costo > off0">Il tuo budget per questa busta dopo la seconda offerta è: <b>{{budget1=budget0}}</b> fantamilioni.</div>*
     <p ng-model="plusvalenza2" ng-show="confronto(selectedItem2.costo, giocAcq2.costo)">Questa offerta ti garantisce una plusvalenza di {{plusvalenza(selectedItem2.costo,giocAcq2.costo)}} fantamilioni per la prossima busta nella quale avrai a disposizione</p>
    </div>
   
</div>
<br />
<!-- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% offerta3-->
<div class="row"> 
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
             <label>Vendere:</label>
             <select ng-model="selectedItem3"  ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
             <label>Acquistare:</label>
             <select ng-model="giocAcq3" ng-options="(lib.nome+' '+lib.costo) for lib in giocLiberi | filter:{ruolo:selectedItem3.ruolo}"></select>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-1">
             <label>Offerta:</label>
             <select ng-model="off2" style="width: 60px"  ng-options="page for page in range(giocAcq3.costo, (budget0-off0-off1)--selectedItem3.costo)"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
        <label></label>
        <!--<div ng-model="budget2">Il tuo budget dopo la seconda offerta e': <b>{{budget2=calcoloBudget(selectedItem2.costo, off1, budget1)}}</b> fantamilioni</div>-->
        *<div ng-model="budget2" ng-if="selectedItem2.costo < off1">Il tuo budget per questa busta dopo la seconda offerta è: <b>{{budget2=calcoloBudget(selectedItem2.costo, off1, budget1)}}</b> fantamilioni.</div>
        <div ng-model="budget2" ng-if="selectedItem2.costo > off1">Il tuo budget per questa busta dopo la seconda offerta è: <b>{{budget2budget1}}</b> fantamilioni.</div>*
     <p ng-model="plusvalenza3" ng-show="confronto(selectedItem3.costo, giocAcq3.costo)">Questa offerta ti garantisce una plusvalenza di {{plusvalenza(selectedItem3.costo, giocAcq3.costo)}} fantamilioni per la prossima busta</p>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<!-- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% offerta4-->
<div class="row"> 
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
             <label>Vendere:</label>
             <select ng-model="selectedItem4"  ng-options="(rosa.nome+' '+rosa.costo) for rosa in rose"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
             <label>Acquistare:</label>
             <select ng-model="giocAcq4" ng-options="(lib.nome+' '+lib.costo) for lib in giocLiberi | filter:{ruolo:selectedItem4.ruolo}"></select>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-1">
             <label>Offerta:</label>
     <select ng-model="off3" style="width: 60px"  ng-options="page for page in range(giocAcq4.costo, (budget0-off0-off1-off2)--selectedItem4.costo)"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label></label>
      
       *<div ng-if="selectedItem3.costo < off2">{{budget3=calcoloBudget(selectedItem3.costo, off2, budget2)}}</div>
        <div ng-if="selectedItem3.costo > off2">{{budget3=budget2}}</div>*
     <p ng-model="plusvalenza4" ng-show="confronto(selectedItem4.costo, giocAcq4.costo)">Questa offerta ti garantisce una plusvalenza di {{plusvalenza(selectedItem4.costo,giocAcq4.costo)}} fantamilioni per la prossima busta</p>
    </div>

</div>
<label></label>
<div ng-model="avanzo">Confermando queste offerte avrai a disposozione, per le prossime buste, un budget pari a <b>{{calcoloBudget(selectedItem4.costo, off3, budget3)}}</b> più le plusvalenze indicate al lato di ogni offerta.</div>
</div>
```

My actually problem is in the assigning function results to different variables:
`budget1=calcoloBudget(arg1,arg2,arg3)` and `budget1=budget0` works only the first time, 
in the second assignment `budget2=calcoloBudget(arg4, arg5, arg6)` and `budget2=budget1` doesn't works.
So as in the third assignemmen. I have no idea why?
I suppose it is not possible to assign a variable more than one time. Any suggest?

Comment: Suggest you create a simple demo that replicates your problem. It's not entirely clear what the problem is. Not sure why you assign `$scope.newBudget` as that will get over written by repeating elements

Comment: it not easy for me create a simple example...my problem is thath the first time i call budget1=calcoloBudget(selectedItem1.costo, off0, budget0) it assign the result to budget1, but the second time in budget2=calcoloBudget(selectedItem2.costo, off1, budget1) it not seems to assign the new value to budget2.